# Communication between Controller and Main class in JavaFX?

Tags: javafx

I am using IntelliJ and as some might know, there is a nicely ordered template project structure of a Main.java, a Controller.java and a FXML.fxml file.

I want to use this and I am trying to switch between 2 Scenes by clicking a Button which is defined in the FXML document. I wonder, how I am able to change the stage which lies in the Main.java when the Controller is called by clicking the button. Of course, it would be possible to make the Stage and the Scene static in the Main.java but it kinda is hard to call it then from the controller.
[This does work but it looks awful in the Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NIghf.png)

[Take a look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVvhz.png)
I am quite new to FX and I though there might be better possibilities than the one I choose. I wondered if I should declare Stage stage and the Scenes in Controller instead.

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to SO! This question has actually been answered many, many times on this site. A couple things to keep in mind as well: 1) Do not post code as screenshots; copy/paste it directly into your question. 2) Do a search through the site before asking a question; there is a good chance it may already have an answer.

Comment: You will also get better responses if you read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and take it seriously.

Answer (score 0):

I would pass a runnable that switches the scenes as a parameter to the Controller.

First instead of defining the controller in the FXML file, define it in your Main class like this.

```
FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getRessource("Scene1.fxml");
fxmlLoader.setController(new Controller());
scene1 = fxmlLoader.load();
```

This allows you to pass parameters to the controller's constructor. So know pass a Runnable as a parameter which will switch the scenes. Like this:

Instead of :

```
new Controller()
```

Do

```
new Controller(() -> {
    //Code to switch scenes
});
```

P.S. This is a lambda expression. You could instead move the content to a separate method and pass the method as the parameter.

Finally, make your controller class look like this

```
/*
 * The method to run when the button is pressed. Passed in as a parameter when the controller was created
 */
private final Runnable switchScenes;

public Controller(Runnable switchScenes) {
    this.switchScenes = switchScenes;
}

@FXML
public void handleSwitchButton(){
    switchScenes.run();
}
```

This makes the following. When the button is pressed, the switchScenes Runnable is executed. This Runnable is the Runnable that was passed from the main class to the controller as a parameter in the constructor. The Runnable contains the code to switch the scenes. Note : This requires  Java 8. For Java 7 you could use an interface with an anonymous class.

On an other note, I recommend switching roots instead of scenes (aka. only one scene and you call scene.setRoot()). This gives you more flexibility (ex. You can add a fade transition when switching).